# How to debug mysql queries from admin area in vue js component?

Tags: vue.js, shopware6

When you write a component that accesses the repository and generates search Criteria, how do you debug the request to the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to find the API request your component caused under the network tab of your browsers dev tools. If you're in a `dev` environment, then you should find a URL to the Symfony Profiler page for that request as value of the header `X-Debug-Token-Link`. On the Profiler page you'll probably be able to find the Query under the Doctrine tab.