# Shopware 6: Unexcpected behavior on custom product extension

Tags: administration, shopware6

what exactly is the purpose or the expected behavior of the `autoload` parameter in `CustomExtension->extendFields()` `OneToOneAssociation` of a [custom extension](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/framework/data-handling/add-complex-data-to-existing-entities#adding-a-field-with-database)?

As i understand, with true the extension is always loaded, even if no has record, maybe as `null`

Expected

```
// debug source
...
product: Proxy
  [[Handler]]: Object
  [[Target]]: Object
    ...
    extensions:
      my_custom_extension: null
```

Actual

```
 // debug source
...
product: Proxy
  [[Handler]]: Object
  [[Target]]: Object
    ...
    extensions: {}
```

**EDIT**

```
// ProductFactoryProductExtension.php
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace ItR22ProductFactory\Extension\ProductFactoryProduct;

use Shopware\Core\Content\Product\ProductDefinition;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\EntityExtension;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Field\OneToOneAssociationField;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\FieldCollection;

class ProductFactoryProductExtension extends EntityExtension
{

    public function extendFields(FieldCollection $collection): void
    {
        $collection->add(
            new OneToOneAssociationField(
                'productFactoryProduct',
                'id',
                'product_id',
                ProductFactoryProductExtensionDefinition::class,
                true
            )
        );
    }

    public function getDefinitionClass(): string
    {
        return ProductDefinition::class;
    }
}
```

```
// ProductFactoryProductExtensionDefinition.php
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace ItR22ProductFactory\Extension\ProductFactoryProduct;

use Shopware\Core\Content\Product\ProductDefinition;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\EntityDefinition;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Field\BoolField;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Field\FkField;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Field\Flag\PrimaryKey;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Field\Flag\Required;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Field\IdField;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Field\JsonField;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Field\OneToOneAssociationField;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\FieldCollection;

class ProductFactoryProductExtensionDefinition extends EntityDefinition
{
    public const ENTITY_NAME = 'product_factory_product';

    public function getEntityName(): string
    {
        return self::ENTITY_NAME;
    }

    public function getEntityClass(): string
    {
        return ProductFactoryProductEntity::class;
    }

    protected function defineFields(): FieldCollection
    {
        return new FieldCollection([
            (new IdField('id', 'id'))->addFlags(new Required(), new PrimaryKey()),
            new FkField('product_id', 'productId', ProductDefinition::class),
            (new BoolField('combinable', 'combinable')),
            (new JsonField('combinations', 'combinations')),
            new OneToOneAssociationField(
                'product',
                'product_id',
                'id',
                ProductDefinition::class,
                false
            )
        ]);
    }
}
```

**EDIT #2**

```
// sw-product-detail/index.js
...
Component.override('sw-product-detail', {
  ...
  
  /**
   *
   */
   loadProduct() {
      this.productCriteria.addAssociation('productFactoryProduct');
      this.$super('loadProduct');
   },
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want data associated to an entity be fetched as well, in most cases the association needs to be actively added by calling `Criteria::addAssociation`. By setting `autoload` of the association field to true, the association is always added internally. Note that for `OneToOneAssociation` the default value of `autoload` is `true`.

Comment: thx for your answer, but even with `Criteria::addAssociation` the expected extension is still missing


`// extended component
loadProduct() {
            this.productCriteria.addAssociation('myExtension');
            this.$super('loadProduct');
        },`

`// debug
productCriteria: Criteria
 ...
   18: {association: 'myExtension', criteria: Criteria}

...
product: Proxy
  ...
  extensions: Object
    __ob__: Observer {value: {…}, dep: Dep, vmCount: 0}
    [[Prototype]]: Object`

Comment: Please add the full contents of your `EntityExtension` and of your custom `EntityDefinition` to your original question. Otherwise we can only guess. One idea: Did you add the `ApiAware` flag to your field? `(new OneToOneAssociationField(...))->addFlags(new ApiAware())`

Comment: Done, see above. Btw, `ApiAware` what is that? Any link to shopware docu for deeper explanation?

Comment: See the [ADR](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/trunk/changelog/release-6-3-5-1/2021-01-25-added-api-aware-flag.md) regarding `ApiAware`. Since it looks like you're using the admin api it shouldn't be a concern though. At first glance the code looks good to me. You're overriding an existing component in the admin? Maybe share the code for the override as well. You can also look at the query to see if a join to the table of your custom entity is included: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73153309/how-to-debug-mysql-queries-from-admin-area-in-vue-js-component/73155120#73155120

Comment: Code snippet of overridden component see above. You say, with this code, the extension has to be loaded and available in the product props?

Comment: Yes, all looks good and data should be available as `product.extensions.productFactoryProduct` given `product_factory_product ` has corresponding entries. If it still isn't I would go ahead with process of elimination as described and check that the resulting query has joins on `product_factory_product`.